# datatable - multiple tables on same page, but only one is responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have three datatables on my page:

```
<table class="driving-table">
  -- table #1--
</table>
<table class="driving-table">
  -- table #2--
</table>
<table class="driving-table">
  -- table #3--
</table>
```

This is the JS that I use to initialise my tables:

```
var table = $('table.driving-table').DataTable({
    rowReorder: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "bFilter": true,
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'print'
    ],
    "paging":   false, //Hide the "Show entries" and "Paging"
    "bInfo": false                  
});

//Searching:
$('#top_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
        table.search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

However, using above, I am only able to get the `search` input to work on table #3. same goes for the `buttons`

**[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawaaavt/2/)** that is showing the issue.

As you can see, only the bottom table is searchable, and only the bottom tables buttons is being placed in `.button-holder`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First things first, don't use the same `id` for more than one `DOM` element

Comment: Ah, good point. Not sure why I have id = drivingtable in the tables, since I don't use it. I will remove it.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be initializing 3 different datatables like this. I'd make the ids `drivingtable1, drivingtable2, drivingtable3` and then initialize all 3 of them separately with 3 different objects `table1, 2 and 3`. But that's just me. Maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: @philantrovert according to their official documentation, this is the way to initialize multiple tables: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html

Comment: I updated the fiddle. I think it's working but then again, there would be another way if it's in their documentation. https://jsfiddle.net/rawaaavt/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tables()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/tables()) API method as shown below:

```
$('#top_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
   table.tables().search( this.value ).draw();
});

table.tables().buttons().container()
   .appendTo( '.button-holder' );
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawaaavt/7/) for code and demonstration.