# datatables - multiple tables on same page, but only one appending buttons

Tags: javascript, datatables, semantic-ui

I'm using `semantic-ui` and have 2 tables, only the top table is appending the buttons:

Head

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'default/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'default/dataTables.semanticui.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'default/buttons.semanticui.min.css' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'default/jquery-3.3.1.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'default/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'default/dataTables.semanticui.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'default/semantic.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'default/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/buttons.semanticui.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/buttons.colVis.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'DataTables/Buttons-1.6.3/js/buttons.print.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Tables:

```html
<table class="ui selectable very compact celled striped table">
  -- table #1--
</table>
<table class="ui selectable very compact celled striped table">
  -- table #2--
</table>
```

My javascript:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('table.ui').DataTable( {
        "paging": false,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "buttons": [ 'copy', 'excel', 'print', 'colvis' ]
        } );
        table.buttons().container()
            .appendTo( $('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );
    } );
```

I've tried using the below suggestion with no success:

[datatable - multiple tables on same page, but only one is responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286375/datatable-multiple-tables-on-same-page-but-only-one-is-responding)

Comment: Version of DT ?

Comment: DataTables-1.10.21

Comment: It should work... https://jsfiddle.net/fou692nb/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not using semantic-ui.